# openapi3 - how to make a bad request example

Tags: api, swagger, openapi

In openapi3-format, how would I specify an example for a bad request?
I assumed like this, but apparently all examples from to parameters block are expected in one examples block in the response?

By bad request I mean an example with data leading to another status code then 200.

The example below seems to be valid as far as the IDE can tell, but works not as intended. Some tools even consider it as wrong.

- when I mock it with [swaggerhub](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/paflov/xxx/1#/default/get_test) or [prism](https://github.com/stoplightio/prism) I can only get the `good`- example, regardless of what I provide for the `a`-param
  1` 200 response
- same with postman mock-server
- when I try to convert it to [API Blueprint 1A](https://apiblueprint.org/) format with [APImatic](https://www.apimatic.io), to mock with [Snowboard](https://github.com/bukalapak/snowboard/) for example, I get errors about the example syntax. Eame with several other tools.

```yaml
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      summary: test

      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: a
          examples:
            good:
              value: 1
            bad:
              value: 0
            good2:
              value: 2


      responses:
        "200":
          description: good
          content:
            text/plain:
              examples:
                good:
                  value: "good example 1"
                good2:
                  value: "good example 2"

        "401":
          description: bad
          content:
            text/plain:
              examples:
                bad:
                  value: "bad example"
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "bad request example" and how your current definition does not suit your needs?

Comment: Please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: Are you sure those mocking tools support business logic, i.e. can vary the mock response based on the input values? You'll probably need to implement an actual live server that would handle the inputs as required.

Comment: No, I am absolutely not sure. I hoped so, because the spec would make it possible and it would make sense. But maybe it's to far logic for a mock-server indeed.